# Use components from local npm repository in an Angular 2 application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, d3.js, npm

I have implemented a generic chart component with d3 and Angular 2. Then published it in a local **npm** repository so that anyone can use that chart component in their Angular project simply by running **npm install my-chart** command.

I created a basic Angular 2 project to reuse my chart component. Then run **npm install my-chart --save**, it added **"@my/my-chart": "^1.0.0"** to the package.json. But there is a problem running **ng serve**, it prompt following error on my console.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'd3' in '...\node_modules\@my\my-chart'
```

Do I need to install D3 in my Angular project? But I think it's better to bundle d3 with the chart component when we run **npm install my-chart**.

What would be the best to to?

package.json file for the published package:

```
{
  "name": "@my/my-chart",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "author": "rosew",
  "main": "./index.js",
  "keywords": [
    "button",
    "card"
  ]
}
```

package.json file for the consuming package:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.6",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "zone.js": "0.7.6",

    "@my/core": "1.1.176",
    "@my/my-button": "^1.0.9",
    "@my/my-chart": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.31",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "4.4.2",
    "typescript": "2.0.3"
  }
```

Comment: Can you post snippets the package.json file for the published package and the consuming package (specifically the dependencies part)

Comment: @TimLewis I have posted them. Could you please check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the project can't find d3 is that no where in there is it specified as a dependency, so it can't be included.

You have two options:

First option is to add d3 as a dependency to your library and it will get loaded on the installation of the @my/my-chart.

Second option and the better way to do this, is to add d3 as a peer dependency to your library. This forces the consuming library to be importing d3. There are several good reasons for this, such as giving the consumer more control of the dependencies and reducing the overlap if more than one dependency require d3.

One thing to not with either options is make sure that the dependency on d3 is as broad as possible so that you are not locked into a version as d3 releases updates.

**my-chart package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@my/my-chart",
  ...
  "peerDependencies": {
    "d3": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

**consumer package.json**

```
{
  "name": "consuming-package",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "^4.6.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add d3 typings as well  as a peer dependency to my library? Bcz I wanted d3 typings as well when I was implementing the library.

Comment: That depends, if all your consumers are going to be using typescript then it doesn't really matter. But having it there forces all users to bring in the typings regardless of whether they use them or not.

Comment: I added d3 as a peer dependency to my library. now I am getting this error. npm WARN @my/my-chart@1.0.3 requires a peer of d3@4.4.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN codelyzer@2.0.0-beta.1 requires a peer of tslint@~4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN codelyzer@2.0.0-beta.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@~2.2.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN codelyzer@2.0.0-beta.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@~2.2.0 but none was installed.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the package.json for both projects. But basically `@my/my-chart@1.0.3 requires a peer of d3@4.4.4 but none was installed` is saying you've specified a peer dependency in my-chart that you are not bringing in through the consuming project. The reason for that this that my-charts says it needs the d3 but it leaves the responsibility up to the consuming package.

Comment: That means we need to install d3 separately in the consumer package, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the preferred way of doing it, if you look at the answer that is the second option I detailed. The first option is to bundle it with your library but I detailed several reasons why not to do this.

Comment: Ok Tim, I got it. Now it's working. Thanks for your concern.